# Angular Directive - Scope returns 0 instead of value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following Angular directive:

```
var OrgChartDirective = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            source     : '=',
            container  : '=',
            stack      : '=',
            depth      : '=',
            interactive: '=',
            showLevels : '=',
            clicked    : '=' // We use '=' here rather than '&' for this callback function
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var target = $(element);
            var source = $('#' + scope.source);
            var options = {
                container  : target,
                nodeClicked: scope.clicked,
                stack      : scope.stack,
                depth      : scope.depth,
                interactive: scope.interactive,
                showLevels : scope.showLevels
            };
            console.log("Drawing org chart at " + scope.source + " on " + target);
            console.log(scope);
            source.orgChart(options);
        }
    }
};
```

I add it to the page like:

`<org-chart source='list-for-wf'/>` or `<div org-chart source='list-for-wf'> </div>`

Problem is, in my console, I see:

`Drawing org chart at 0 on [object Object]`

Why is the source returning `0`, this is like jquery when you try to access an invalid element.  Even if I log the `source` as the first line of the link function it is `0`

Why is that?  I have tried `data-source="..."` and all kinds of stuff.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you try changing `source: '='` to `source: '@'`

Comment: This works as well, thanks!

Comment: Implication of changing '=' to '@' is that you are happy for your source to be bound 1 way only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are read as javascript expressions, so `source="list-for-wf"` is being interpreted as "the variable `list` minus the keyword `for` minus the variable `wf`".  (I'm a bit surprised Angular doesn't throw an error on that keyword instead of returning zero, but hey.)

I think you want a quoted string instead: `<org-chart source="'list-for-wf'">`